# Variable classname in javascript

Tags: class, variables, javascript

Is there a way to make a variable classname in javascript. In php the next is allowed:

```
$classname = "klasse";
$class = new $classname();
```

Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/):

```
some_object["string_containing_method_name"]();
```

If you want to play with globals, then just remember they are all properties of the `window` object.

… but [don't play with globals](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/).

Your particular example:

```
var $classname = "klasse";
var $class = new window[$classname]();
```

(Obviously, the usual conventions for only using $ in machine generated code should apply too)

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that "[eval is evil](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)", but if you are aware of this, then:

```
var classname= "klasse";
eval( "var obj = new " + classname + "();");
```

Comment: @David (author of a deleted comment that stated that `eval` shouldn't be used), that's why I added the disclaimer. However, the question sounds more theoretical than soon to be put to practical use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call something like

```
new acme.tools.Hammer();
```

Then do

```
var $toolName = "Hammer";
var myObject = new window['acme']['tools'][$toolName]();
```